# How to convert string variable to float variable JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to read string from JSON file and convert it to float. Other data in the file are integers, but this specific data is string.

JSON File:

```
{
"Valuation": {
    "TrailingPE": 29.4035,
    "ForwardPE": 28.66,
    "PriceSalesTTM": 5.5067,
    "PriceBookMRQ": 44.6301,
    "EnterpriseValue": 2906817822720,
    "EnterpriseValueRevenue": 5.9171,
    "EnterpriseValueEbitda": 23.52
},"Income_Statement": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2023-09-30": {
                "date": "2023-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2023-11-03",
                "currency_symbol": "USD",
                "researchDevelopment": "7307000000.00",
                "effectOfAccountingCharges": null,
                "incomeBeforeTax": "26998000000.00",
                "minorityInterest": null,
                "netIncome": "22956000000.00",
                "sellingGeneralAdministrative": "6151000000.00",
                "sellingAndMarketingExpenses": null,
                "grossProfit": "40427000000.00",
                "reconciledDepreciation": "2653000000.00",
                "ebit": "26969000000.00",
                "ebitda": "29622000000.00",
                "depreciationAndAmortization": "2653000000.00",
                "nonOperatingIncomeNetOther": null,
                "operatingIncome": "26969000000.00",
                "otherOperatingExpenses": "62529000000.00",
                "interestExpense": "1002000000.00",
                "taxProvision": "4042000000.00",
                "interestIncome": "18000000.00",
                "netInterestIncome": null,
                "extraordinaryItems": null,
                "nonRecurring": null,
                "otherItems": null,
                "incomeTaxExpense": "4042000000.00",
                "totalRevenue": "89498000000.00",
                "totalOperatingExpenses": "13458000000.00",
                "costOfRevenue": "49071000000.00",
                "totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet": "29000000.00",
                "discontinuedOperations": null,
                "netIncomeFromContinuingOps": "22956000000.00",
                "netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares": "22956000000.00",
                "preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments": null
            }
}
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('some_url')
data = response.json()

# Write JSON File
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

# Read JSON File
with open('path_to_file/data.json', 'r') as f:
   data = json.load(f)

for statement in data['Income_Statement]['quarterly']['2023-09-30]['netIncome']:
         value_ = float(statement)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

How can I read this string value and convert it to a float value and put it in the value_ variable?

*Note: The JSON file is wrong in the question, but the file is correct in my code and its to big to post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is going through that string character by character, converting one character at a time.  You don't need a `for` loop here.  Just do

```
value = float(data['Income_Statement']['quarterly']['2023-09-30']['netIncome'])
```